How to request for a package to be added to the Fedora repositories?
I am a co-maintainer of an eyestrain prevention app called SafeEyes.
The app is already available on many distributions, but not in Fedora.
What is the procedure to add a new app to the official Fedora repositories?

There's a "packaging requests" wiki page, but it's rather long in backlog, because people that care for software are hard to find.
You will need to find someone who will do the work of maintaining the package – you can volunteer to do that yourself, but I've done that with other software, and: it's a nontrivial amount of work, you don't want to do that "on top" of other things.
If that someone (incl. you) is a new contributor to Fedora, they need an experienced packager to "sponsor" them, i.e. say they will mentor and assist them and vouch for their honesty.
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/ describes the process. You usually start out writing a .spec file for your own software (the openSuSE one might just work!), and show that it builds on your own https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/ repo for the current version of Fedora (40, and rawhide). Once that's done, it's easier to convince people that maintaining this software package is feasible!

There is a wishlist for new packages to be added on Fedora Wiki so you can try adding it there, but I don't think there is a big chance this will work -- the package wishlist is quite long and it doesn't look like people often pick applications from there to package.
So the easiest way is probably to do to become a Fedora Packager and do it yourself. The process is not that complicated and it is described here. And because it is already packaged for openSUSE its SPEC file could be an easy way to start.

‘Already packaged for openSUSE’. Speaking from experience as a packaging engineer who has to support a bunch of different distros, that’s a start, but not as much as you might think. openSUSE is very different in a number of respects from other RPM distros, and there are quite a few strange edge cases that make it challenging to make any nontrivial RPM spec file that works on openSUSE also work on Fedora/RHEL.

I agree but it can be easier than starting from scratch.
